# If you sub-class React class components using OOP-type inheritance, how to do React lifecycle methods get handled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, composition

We are developing a large site using React and have up until this point been using composition.  We are re-evaluating the complexity of our component structure and thinking of re-implementing the components using inheritance and a more OOP-oriented structure.  Without getting into the debate on composition vs inheritance, I'm curious how the lifecycle methods get handled.  Does one simply do something like this:

```
// parent.js

componentDidMount () {
  // do some stuff
}

// child.js

componentDidMount () {
    super.componentDidMount()
    // do some stuff
}
```

Are there any other 'gotchas' to extending base classes, and creating children and grandchildren classes in React? Would code using traditional OOP, extending React component classes, possibly break in a later version of React?

And now to enter into the discussion about composition vs inheritance: we've read the recommendations from React (https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), but in our use-case we want to start with base components and create others that descend from them, growing increasingly specialized.  FB, in the above page, says one should configure more generic components using props.  But we don't want the base level components to know about all the options of all the possible specializations.  That is, the base component, should be simple, and clean, and the more specialized components would simply add that specialized parts they need. Are we missing something?

Comment: the react lifecyle methods or called at different step during the 'commit phase' (when ReactDOM actually mutates the DOM).

They simply instantitate your class and call it using instance.componentDidMount() like here : https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c11015ff4f610ac2924d1fc6d569a17657a404fd/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberCommitWork.js#L423

For the rest, I do not really understand your question (it doesn't mean it's your fault, surely it is mine as my english understanding is fragile)

Comment: It's not an answer, but you might want to look at using Hooks instead of composition. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html Rather than sharing functionality via classes, you do it via functions

Comment: @AndyJ Thanks -- For the moment I don't know if hooks are what we are looking for; even FB in their hooks page seems to be saying "don't rush into this", and our project has to be delivered in six weeks. My conundrum is: let's say we have a class 'box with image', and then want to add a 'callout' to it in some cases, without including that code in our base.  We thought 'make a child class with a callout'.  Maybe that doesn't work with JSX, that is, everything graphical comes not from code per se but from HTML-ish entities, and perhaps the 'render' method doesn't easily allow overriding.

Comment: @Cerulean IMO the "real" answer is "stop thinking in terms of inheritance and start thinking in terms of composition". I can't directly answer your question because I don't know the answer. I don't know if inheritance will work okay, because I've never needed to try it. FB say "don't rush in to hooks", fair enough but they also say "we haven’t found _any_ use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies".

Comment: Thanks. I think you may be right. Our thinking was the following: we have a large number of graphical elements on different pages that could be conceptualized as a simple element, adding on graphical elements.  Thus: inheritance.  But React works (sort of) but spitting out HTML-ish JSX.  That doesn't work very well with OOP.   Thus one turns to composition.  That having been said, if you have, say, five layers of specialization that goes in several different directions...

Comment: ...that is you have 'image with box with one image and one more box of text' and 'image with box with two images but one over the main image and one in the box of text', doesn't it become extremely messy trying to put all those `props` and `children` all over the place in your base class? I mean, you have to account for of the most specialized cases in your base class.